# Is morality "natural", or, is "it's natural" a good moral argument?

Tags: ethics

The title has two questions but they're just different versions of the same question, namely: Is morality natural, or is it a kind of emergent property of consciousness?

Is "it's natural" a good moral argument?

If it's not, it would imply that morality "exists" outside of "naturalness", as something that is innate to humans but that isn't a consequence of evolution or nature in any way.

If it is a good argument, why is it?

Comment: Arguments have premises and conclusions. Can you specify those in the case of "it's natural"? Otherwise it's hard to tell what you mean by that.

Comment: Morality is a survival mechanism social mammals. Immorality leads to chaos. The selfish gene will only allow immorality whilever it furthers genes. If there is chaos, the genes are not propogating at maximum efficiency.

Comment: As worded the question is poorly formulated and seems designed either to invite discussion or push a position rather than to ask a question that fits with the SE formula.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't a good argument.  A "good" argument is grounded in reason and as such will be persuasive to a rational individual.

The argument that "this is morally good because it is natural" isn't convincing at all is it?  That is not to say necessarily that the conclusion is incorrect.

To enhance the strength of the argument, one would need to know and explain why being natural makes things morally good.  One would need to understand the true essence of what "morally good" means and understand why something being "natural" is necessary and sufficient for "moral goodness".

Basically to make a good argument, one needs to begin with assumptions that everyone agrees, and deduce logically from these the desired conclusion.

Comment: Personally I think we arrived at the best definition of 'proper conduct' with the phrase 'do unto others as you would have done to yourself'
Now clearly this definition would define much of 'natural' human behavior as 'bad conduct' or immoral.
The human condition leaves us helpless.. we can perceive the injustice of the struggle of life, but we are powerless to defeat nature. 
So we war, embezzle, hoard....